# How to exclude parts of input from being parsed?

Tags: c++, c, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

OK, so I've set up a complete Bison grammar (+ its Lex counterpart) and this is what I need :

Is there any way I can set up a grammar rule so that a specific portion of input is *excluded* from being parsed, but instead retrieved as-is?

**E.g.**

```
external_code : EXT_CODE_START '{' '}';
```

For instance, how could I **get the part between the curly brackets as a string**, without allowing the parser to consume it (since it'll be "external" code, it won't abide by my current language rules... so, it's ok - text is fine).

How would you go about that?

Should I tackle the issue by adding a *token* to the Lexer? (same as I do with string literals, for example?)

Any ideas are welcome! (I hope you've understood what I need...)

---

**P.S.** Well, I also thought of treating the whole situation pretty much as I do with C-style multiline comments (= capture when the comment begins, in the Lexer, and then - from within a custom function, keep going until the end-of-comment is found). That'd definitely be some sort of solution. But isn't there anything... easier?

Comment: That'd be something you do in the lexer, rather than in the grammar. Otherwise you risk having content that blows up the lexer before the grammar has a chance to decide whether or not to ignore it. Same reason quoted strings, comments, etc. are treated as a single lexical token.

Comment: @keshlam yup, that's what I thought...

Answer (score 2):

You can call the lexer's `input`/`yyinput` function to read characters from the input stream and do something with them (and they won't be tokenized so the parser will never see them).

You can use lexer states, putting the lexer in a different state where it will skip over the excluded text, rather than returning it as tokens.

The problem with either of the above from a parser action is dealing with the parser's one token lookahead, which occurs in some (but not all) cases.  For example, the following will probably work:

```
external_code: EXT_CODE_START '{' { skip_external_code(); } '}'
```

as the action will be in a default reduction state with no lookahead.  In this case, `skip_external_code` could either just set the lexer state (second option above), or it could call `input` until it gets to the matching `}` and then calls `unput` once (first option above).

Note that the `skip_external_code` function needs to be defined in the 3rd section of the the lexer file so it has access to static functions and macros in the lexer (which both of these techniques depend on).